# how to create folder in sonatype nexus repository through command line

Tags: batch-file, sonatype

Is there a way to create folder and copy artifacts into the created folders in sonatype nexus repository, through windows command line or batch files?

Answer (score 3):

I have finally got solution to my problem by curl functionality.

curl -u admin:admin123 -T C:\upload\Test.txt http://Nexus_Repo_URL/folder_to_be_created/Test.txt

"folder_to_be_created" is the folder which is created in the repository and the file, 'Test.txt', is copied to it

Comment: It's working as excepted.

Answer (score 2):

Just upload the artifacts to whatever path is needed using one of the methods described here:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-

Any folders needed will be created automatically.